# Any module which even comes close to frontpage slider module

Tags: 7

I saw this [front page slider module](http://www.frontpageslideshow.net/), and I was impressed by it, but I see there is no Drupal 7 module and it is payed property now.

Is there any module which comes close to this one?

Comment: As WestieUK said, Views Slideshow is a great module to do this. We did a tutorial on how to do this, unfortunately its in spanish: http://rootstack.com/es/blog/sliders-flexibles-con-views-slideshow. Here's an example of what you're looking for, but with bigger dimensions: http://demos.rootstack.com/views-slideshow-demo-1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) is incredibly configable and I am sure it will cater for that type of display. However is it not an off the shelf product like the wordpress example so dont expect to install it and it just work.

Instead like much of Drupal it is more like a construction box, complex but hugely powerful.

Comment: +1 for Views Slideshow. It's really amazing what you can do with it but as WestieUK mentions, it will involve some work. I am theming one right now for a new client site and was even able to make it responsive using the Adaptive Image module as well as having multiple languages work with it using Entity Translation.

Answer (score 4):

WestieUK's answer is good. I used to use things like Views Slideshow and Views Carousel, but found them a bit too bloated (understandably so) and I wasn't able to configure everything I wanted. I've since just grabbed whatever JavaScript library I wanted to use (e.g. [NivoSlider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)) and added the JavaScript files in my theme. You can even use the Views module to build the unordered list of items and then target that  with your jQuery selector that activates the slideshow.

This approach gives you a bit more control.

And, as WestieUK points out, much of Drupal is complex and hugely powerful. To really do things well, you can run your own SQL query in a little custom module to grab the nodes you want, the image style presets, etc., and display them in a render array for use with whatever slideshow library. This kind of thing gives you the leanest, fastest loading, and most customizable slideshow you can get.

Comment: Agreed, if you have the time to go the extra mile though :)